# Does 'will have p.p' include futurity, only when added time adjunct?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs, conditional-constructions

> [i] If he had stayed in the army he would have become a colonel. [remote]
>
> [ii] If he stayed in the army he **will have become** a colonel.  [open]
>
> In [ii] the possible staying in the army and the consequential becoming a colonel are in past time, whereas in [i] only the former necessarily is: the becoming a colonel is simply subsequent to staying in the army and this includes the case where it is still in the future.
>
> (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p203)
>
> We’**ll have lived** here for ten years by next July.
> (Angela Downing, English Grammar, p360)

Consulting Downing’s example, I guess [ii]’s becoming a colonel could include the futurity, when time adjunct is added. As in: “Call me in the morning and I’ll have selected your living quarters.(Invisible Man)”. Is this right, or does [ii] by itself include the futurity?

Comment: Hmmm. I wouldn't presume to say that your grammar book is wrong, because I'm sure there are a lot of usages I'm not familiar with. But [ii] sounds *completely* wrong to me, and I can't understand the explanation being given. [i] makes perfect sense to me; if in the past he had chosen to stay in the army, at some point between that past time and point X (which could be now, before now, on in the future from now) he would have become a colonel. That sounds great. But I'm not getting [ii] at all. *Stayed* and *will have become* don't match for me at all, and I don't see how it thinks *will* is

Comment: past tense there. If I heard this sentence I would be unable to interpret it (much as I am having difficulty doing so now). I would probably assume they meant *would* instead of *will* and ignore what would seem to me to be a mistake. So... Not saying it's wrong, but... It definitely doesn't make sense to me. The only similar thing I can think of would be something like this: "Do you think John will decide to go to college or stay in the army?" "I don't know... If he stayed in the army he will have become a colonel by the time he's 30." But this isn't past tense, it's talking about the future.

Comment: (And in that last example, *stayed* is a bit forced... I interpret it as *If he were to choose to stay* = *If he stayed*, but I think it would actually be more likely to just say "If he stays..." since it hasn't happened yet. So even that is a stretch, and it requires the timeline (at least to me); you have to say something like "X will have happened by the time Y happens." I find this question very, very interesting... I look forward to seeing what others have to say on the subject!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Profs. Hufflepuff are making this appear more complicated than it is.

- [i] involves an irrealis in a past-tense conditional, where the *WILL* form indicates both subsequence and consequence.

  > PRESENT REALIS:
  >   If he stay**s** in the Army he **will** become a colonel.
  >
  > PAST REALIS *or* PRESENT IRREALIS (you can only tell from context):
  >   If he stay**ed** in the Army he **would** become a colonel.
  >
  > PAST IRREALIS:
  >   If he **had** stay**ed** in the Army he **would have** become a colonel.
- [ii], however, doesn’t involve subsequence at all, it’s pure consequence: an *epistemic* *WILL*:

  > A: "Some guy just walked in without knocking and went into the kitchen."
  >   B: "Oh, that will be my roommate Sam, it's OK."

  The sense of [ii] is that a past contingency necessarily has a present result.

  > If he ***did* stay** in the Army it's a virtual certainty that he **has become** a Colonel by now.
- Note that the *would have become* in [i] is what I have [elsewhere (2.3)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13258/32) called a ‘modal sham perfect’, while the *will have become* in [ii] is a genuine modal perfect.

Comment: I think it might be useful to see constructions like your example B in terms of *when the unfolding reality becomes clear [in the **immediate** future]*. To my mind, even though the thing being spoken of is in the past or present, the point in time where everyone knows for sure [who it is, what happened, etc.] lies in the future. Sam's roommate would have to use present or past tense if he'd actually *seen* who it was at the time, because then it wouldn't be possible to rephrase his words as *[if we look into it,] that **will turn out to have been** Sam.*

Comment: @StoneyB, Your description makes me to solve the mysterious word, existential, in CGEL:"The existential or experiential perfect indicates the existence of past events: it asserts that at least one instance of the eventuality named by VERB occurs prior to Reference Time."[source](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it/13258#13258). I always get the impression that your words are tinged with psychology, even though they are dealing with linguistic, grammar issues.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see [ii] as implying or suggesting futurity; the past tense  *stayed* rules that out, in my opinion.

The only scenario I've thought of in which [ii] is grammatically sound reflects lack of knowledge, as illustrated in the following dialogue between Alice and Bob.

> Alice: What ever became of Private O'Donnel?
>   Bob: If he stayed in the Army he will have become a Colonel.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with StoneyB. However, he left out the proper form to actually express what you suggest. The thing is, you do have to specify a certain time in the future to make the construction sensible:
If he stays in the army three more years, he will have become a colonel [by then].

So, IIUC, the really short answer to your title question is:  YES