# Another interpretation of this second conditional sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions

Consider:

> If I met John, I would call my mom.

I know this sentence is a second conditional example, which relates to a hypothetical situation.

But I don't know whether I can also understand it in such a way if the covert context is:

> I may have met him, but I **am** not quite sure about that. My memory
>   can't last that long. The only thing I am sure about is that
>   **whenever** I meet him, I will call my mom **immediately**. Thus, if one day I find out I indeed met John before, I will be sure that I
>   **called** my mom immediately on that occasion.

Comment: I think you mean a _hypothetical_ situation. Do you mean you would call your mom _now_ if you found out about meeting John, or do you mean you _would have_ called her last summer, after meeting John?

Comment: The case is, I am not sure whether I met him sometime last summer, and also I am not sure whether I called my mom.

Comment: This is possible. If I met John last summer, I will call my mom. It means If I find out I indeed met him, my mom will be the first to know this. But this is not the case in my question.

Comment: I am not quite clear about what you are asking here. Please clarify your query.

Comment: My question is that I don't know whether I could also understand it in this way. Is it possible to be explained as above given the context I described?

Comment: Actually, this is starting to sound like my textbook on Mathematical proofs. :D

Comment: Sort of, what I am saying here is just a theoretical possiblity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly why the notion of '1st, 2nd, 3rd conditional' is so useless for anything except getting an initial familiarity with the forms. This sentence, as you conjecture, bears two entirely different meanings in different contexts:

- It may be a *non-past, unreal* conditional:

  > I don't follow football, but in the unlikely event that I ever **met** John Elway I **would call** my mother immediately: she's a huge fan of his.
- It may be a *past, real* conditional:

  > That summer, Mom didn't mind who I played with as long as she knew where I was; so whenever I **met** John I **would** always **call** my mother.

Your scenario—“I am not sure whether I met him sometime last summer. But if I did meet him at that time, I would call my mom and tell her about him.” requires a different construction in the consequence clause, and would probably employ a construction with *do* in the condition clause:

> I don’t remember if I met John last summer; but if I **did** meet him, I **would have called** my mother.

The *n*-conditional model won’t help you with that: it waves the situation off as a ’mixed conditional’.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ... *whom I played with as long as...*?

Comment: **who** is also acceptable, just a little informal. @Maulik V

Comment: Looking back, I tend to think the last example should be like this: I don’t remember if I met John last summer; but if I did meet him, I **will have called** my mother. She's a huge fan of his. What do you think? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng That is possible but very unlikely. Epistemic *will* indicates certainty, and doesn't fit well with the uncertainty in your protasis.

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13265/does-will-have-p-p-include-futurity-only-when-added-time-adjunct/13282#13282 Wouldn't [ii] be same as mine? @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng But both of those refer to present states, not past events; and in the "army" example, the *if* clause is 'echoic', accepting someone else's assurance that he stayed in the army. In your example, you have indicated uncertainty; either *would* or *must* would be natural, but you would use *will* only if you were focusing on somehow checking whether in fact you did call your mother.

Comment: Is it the same to say "I don’t remember if I met John last summer; but if I **had met** him, I would have called my mother.", meaning exactly the same as "..., but if I did meet him, I would have called my mother."?  @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB No: *If I **did meet** him* signifies an open question: you don't remember whether the meeting took place or not. *If I **had met** him* signifies a closed counterfactual: you are certain the meeting did not take place.

Comment: Is it possible to say "I don’t know if John is in Beijing; but if he is there, he **would/will** ask Mary to take care of the children." Do I need to open a new question? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB It's possible, but ordinarily you'd say *he would have asked*, because ordinarily he would have made that arrangement **before** going to Beijing.

Comment: I thought so, what about this: "I don’t know if John is in Beijing; but if he is there, he **would/will** visit the Great Wall." ^_^ @StoneyB Does "would" here hint at uncertainty of his visit?

Comment: @KinzleB I'd be uncomfortable with *would* there, though you might hear it in conversation. *Would* isn't quite symmetrical with the other modals: you could use *could* or *might* or *should* there, but *would* implies nonfactuality.

Comment: Terrific! BTW, you said "I'd be uncomfortable with.." because you mean _under no circumstances_ you would be comfortable with.., right? And you said "you could use..". Is the **could** the same as in "we **could** write a letter to the director.", used to suggest something?

Comment: @KinzleB The *would* means more I'd would be uncomfortable writing it - it would feel wrong. The *could* is a mix of permission and ability - it would be OK to do that - but pastform because that's hypothetical: you haven't indicated any intention of using *could* or *might* or *should*. ... But ALL these answers are after the fact: I didn't consider them in writing the comment.

Comment: Wow, this is new to me; each time I think I have figured it out, it only turns out I'm still in the dark. Would it be OK to say "you **can/may** use _could_ or _might_ or _should_..."? Any nuances suggested? :)

Comment: @KinzleB Sure you can. Or may. I can, too; or at least I could, but I didn't. It's all very fuzzy. There are no bright lines.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to past tense with your question.

"If I met John, I would call my mom," is a possible situation in the future or hypothetical.

"If I had met John, I would have called my mom," is what you would say if you are talking about meeting John last Summer.

Comment: I am talking about past. As I have said, I already knew this usage of hypothetical situation. I just thought about another possibility, given my context.

Comment: It could also be, "If I met John, I would have called my mom."

Comment: Nope, in your case, it should be "if I had met John".

Comment: "If I met John, I would call my mom," is not proper for past tense.  The reason is the use of "would call". That is a "going to" phrase.  To make it past tense you need you to use "would have called".  So, the context for this is not interchangeable between past and hypothetical statements without changing the tense of the sentence.

Comment: I think you are not asking my question here. I have known the way you explained. @iolympian

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but

"I don't know whether I could also understand it in this way: The context is, I am not sure whether I met him sometime last summer. But if I did meet him at that time, I would call my mom and tell her about him."

It sounds like you are asking whether you could interpret that sentence as being that you met him last summer.

To answer that, you cannot interpret the sentence that way.

Comment: I might have met him, but I am not very sure about that. My memory can't last that long. The only thing I am sure about is that whenever I meet him, I will call my mom. This is the context.

Comment: But, iolympian is right. Your context makes it a third conditional case.

Comment: Then, it is not about hypothetical situation. If so, why is "would have called" used? I think that it can be only used in the main clause to indicate the hypothetical consequence. But in my case, It was possible that I called my mom. I just don't quite remember now. @snailplane

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. The issue is that the sentence does not convey "past tense met John" future tense "call mom".  
  
"If I found out I had met John, I would call my mom."  
"If I remember whether I met John, I would call my mom."  
"If I had met John, I may have called my mom."  
  
But,  
  
"If I met John, I would call my mom," cannot be read as-is as anything other than a future hypothetical. Doing so would be forcing the language and anyone who is a native English speaker would misunderstand what you are meaning, thinking you mean future.

Comment: @Zhanlong: I think you are mistakenly assuming English tenses are far more "precise" than is really the case. There are many different ways of interpreting your example sentence, and even messing about with perfect aspects *(had met, would have called)* won't disambiguate much. The context would normally make it clear what you mean, but a contrived example sentence standing in isolation is a completely different ball game.

Comment: Good point! That's why I added the context in the last paragraph. @FumbleFingers YES, I am trying to make simple things more complicated for the sake of discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

- You may, or may not, have met John last summer.
- After meeting John, the thing you would surely do is call your mother.

Then you can say:

> If I met John last summer, I would have called my mother.

Now, to find out whether you met John, you can ask your mother if you called her. :)

Your original sentence, however, cannot be interpreted that way.

The only possibility would be to read it as

> If I met John last summer (and I somehow remembered that *now*), I would call my mother (now, immediately - or in the very near future, right after remembering whether I met him).

That is, however, such a far-fetched interpretation, that is is highly unlikely that *anyone* would ever read the sentence like that.

Comment: If i say it in your way, then it is not about a hypothetical situation. If so, why is "would have called" used? I think that it can be only used in the main clause to indicate the hypothetical consequence. But in my case, It was possible that I called my mom. I just don't quite remember now. @oerkelens

Comment: I wanted to stay as close as possible to your original :) To fully explain the situation without misunderstandings, one would say something like "If I did actually meet John last summer, I'm sure I would have called my mom. Maybe I should check with her."

Comment: Then, what is the usage of "would have" here? I have never seen it being used like that.

Comment: It simply indicates that it might or might not have happened. If I say "I called my mom", it is a fact. I do not know if I called her or not. If I say "I would call her", I is not referring to anything in the past. (It _could_, in a sentence like "When I was a kid, every time I saw John, I would call my mom.")

Comment: This is never examined in any grammar book i have read. I don't think "would have" here is interchangeable with "might have". Right? I know exactly how each of what you have listed above stands for different situation. But this "would have" comes out of nowhere. I wonder how "would have" match my original context. Why choose it, although obviously other alternatives do not fit. Plz help me! @oerkelens

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng *Would have called* is not a perfect construction (modal verbs have no participles, so they cannot be cast in the perfect), but the construction used to 'backshift' into the past a past-tense form employed with present reference. For instance: present-tense "I should like a cookie (today)" would be backshifted as "I should have liked a cookie (yesterday)".

Comment: I knew that is not a perfect construction. I just wonder why "Would have called" can collocate with an if-clause which does not refer to a hypothetical scenario. And is it a backshifted version of "If I meet John, I will call my mother." @StoneyB

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Because it's still hypothetical (just not counterfactual); and because *would*, like the other modals, is as often as not a present indicative form, no longer distinctly marked for either pastness or hypotheticality. It's a past marker, to eliminate the ambiguity of **would*.

Answer (score -1):

> If I met John, I would call my mom.

You say you are not sure whether you met him in the summer.  So here are the possibilities:
A)You met John. So you called your mom.
B)You did not meet John. So you didn't call your mom  either.

But then, you did not mention anything about ***when*** you would call your mom. So if get to know, that did meet him, I would call my mom up then.

But with your interpretation there are three 'catches' :
1) The time when you would call your mom isn't mentioned, so your assumption is wrong. You may or may not call her up immediately.
2) There is no way to be sure that you would have immediately called up your mom, right after you met John (from 1)
3)A reference to the past requires the sentence to be in the form : If I had [past participle(x)], then I would have [past participle(y)]. 
So your sentence actually refers to the future.

From these catches, we can conclude that your interpretation is wrong

Note :
See [English Conditional Sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences)

Comment: I have updated my question. Now you can know **when**.

Comment: But the original statement doesn't say that. Therefore, your assumption may be false.

Comment: OK, what should I say in order to express that meaning?

Comment: Change the original sentence. Simple.

Comment: I know, but how?

Comment: What I meant to say was, with the sentence you gave us, it is impossible to come to the conclusions that you have come to. So your interpretation is wrong.